# jquery select checkboxes in nested gridview when parent checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I would like to check the checkboxes of all of the rows in a nested gridview is the checkbox of the parent is checked. Or uncheck all of the checkboxes in the nested gridview when the parent is unchecked.

I found a jquery example that almost fits my needs.  However, when you select a checkbox in the parent grid, it checks all of the checkboxes in the parent grid and all children grids.  I would like it to check all of the boxes in only the child grid.

The problem, I believe, is identifying the correct grid to update the checkboxes.
The line, **var grid = $(this).closest("table");**, traverses up the tree and selects all of the districts.
I need to idenitify the InternalGrid of this district.  But I have tried using .children() and several of things but it is not working.

So how to I identify the InternalGrid of the district that has been selected?

The jquery is as follows:

```
 $("[id*=District]").live("click", function () 
 {
        var chkHeader = $(this);

        var grid = $(this).closest("table");

        $("input[type=checkbox]", grid).each(function ()   
        {
            if (chkHeader.is(":checked"))   
            {
                $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
            } 
            else 
            {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
            }
        });       
    });
```

Thanks

Here is the HTML:

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="District" SortExpression="district" HeaderStyle-Width="200px">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("district")%>');">
            <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("district")%>" width="10px" border="0" src="Images/plus.png" /> </a> 
            <asp:CheckBox ID="District" Text='<%#Bind("district")%>' runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="200px"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField> 

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Server" HeaderStyle-Width="280px">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList DataTextField="Server" DataValueField="Server" ID="DropDownList2" Runat="server" >
           <asp:ListItem>A1</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>A2</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>Both</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

                <tr><td colspan="100%">  
                <div id="div<%# Eval("district") %>" style="display:none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">

                      <asp:GridView ID="InternalGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" 
                           BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px"  HorizontalAlign="Center"
                           GridLines="Both" ShowHeader="True" ShowFooter="False" >
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" ForeColor="#E7E7FF"></HeaderStyle>
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Station"  SortExpression="number">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="Station" Text='<%#Bind("number")%>' runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="130px"></ItemStyle>
                             </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Server" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList DataTextField="Server" DataValueField="Server" ID="DropDownList2" Runat="server" >
                                   <asp:ListItem>A1</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem>A2</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem>Both</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="130px"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeZone" HeaderText="Time Zone" SortExpression="timeZone">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="130px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>

                             <asp:BoundField DataField="ServerType" HeaderText="Server Type" SortExpression="serverType">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="135px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>

                       </Columns>
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    </div> 
                 </td></tr> 
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="305px"></HeaderStyle>
             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="280px"/>
         </asp:TemplateField>                                    
    </Columns>
<BoundaryStyle BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid"></BoundaryStyle>
<RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
</cc1:CoolGridView>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your checkbox in child gridview? and you want to change parent row color when checkbox is checked?

Comment: There is a checkbox in the parent row. When checked, the row will change color. (that works). I want to add when the parent checkbox is checked, the child checkboxes in the grid view are also checked.  It is a nested gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out!
In case someone out there is struggling with something like this.
This is what worked for me...

Just need to set the grid variable using the ID of the child grid.
So replace this line:
    var grid = $(this).closest("table");

With these lines:
    var $checkboxLabel =  "[id*=div" + $(this).next('label').text() + "]";
    var nestedGrid = $($checkboxLabel);

That's it.